# Magento 2 - Location of .phtml containing page header

Tags: magento2, template

I'm creating a custom template and am trying to figure out which .phtml needs to be extended so I can edit the page header. I would like to edit the links: Sign in or Create an Account.

Using the debug template path hints, I don't see a .phtml that encompasses the page header unlike subscribe.phtml for the footer/subscribe/newsletter and copyright.phtml for the copyright banner.

=======

**EDIT**: Used PhpStorm to recursively search the entire project for the text 'panel wrapper' and it was found in:

public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout

- line 11 of default.xml

However, in my template's composer.json I have 'magento/theme-frontend-luma' in the require field.

Comment: Turn on template hints in store>configuration>advanced>developer to see what template goes where on the front-end.

Comment: @Aaron I've used template hints but it doesn't show anything for panel header

Comment: Could you specify what sort of change you want to make to those links?

Comment: @Aaron I would like to edit the current link names, add some icons and create new links

Comment: You can't do this by simply editing template files. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do it. Those elements are not coming from a template, they are generated by block classes in the Magento_Customer module.

The easiest way to do this that I've found would be to make a module with a custom block, template, and default.xml layout. You'd remove the 'header.links' block and then insert your own block and template. You would just need your block class to contain the logic to display which links depending on whether customer is logged in.

To remove the existing block and insert your own, just add the following code to your default.xml within the body tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links" display="false"/>

        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Me\MyModule\Block\MyBlock" template="Me_MyModule::mytemplate.phtml" name="top.mylinks"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you are not creating a template based off a custom theme, try looking in:

**/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml**

Note: This is based off my knowledge of 1.X, not sure of changes since 2.X

Comment: Yea I thought it would be in header.phtml but it has contents to populate the panel header div

Comment: Magento 2 is not like magento 1 in the way that it builds its elements, the header is built with knockoutjs and not a .phtml file.